# summing columns in a row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How would I do something like this in PL/SQL (Oracle 11)?

```
select 
  1 as aa,
  2 as bb,
  3 as cc,
  (aa + bb + cc) as total
from my_table;
```

to yield this:

```
-------------------------
aa   bb   cc     total
-------------------------
1    2    3      6
-------------------------
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: basically what you see in the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT aa,bb,cc,aa+bb+cc as total 
FROM (
    SELECT 1 as aa,
           2 as bb,
           3 as cc
    FROM My_Table)
```

If so, I don't understand why use `My_Table` and not dual..

Comment: Thanks.  The reason my_table is in the query is the snippet of code is the simplest form of the statement I will eventually be writing, and there will be additional queries from 'my_table'

Comment: OK, but did this answer your need ? @WOPR

Comment: What if a or b or c is null :) ... you will output null  @WOPR

Comment: 1 , 2 , 3 are here as way to illustrate the question in understandable way, correct me if am wrong, and my message is a question (What if null) @WOPR

Comment: @sagi I'm not sure why you think we can't comment on your answer and raise a valid point and also ask something of the OP? I see nothing wrong with that, especially if it's for clarification purposes - which is what I read Digital Alchemist's comments to be.

Comment: I think I didn't explain my self well, I was talking specificly on this case, when Digital has posted a comment here with the exact thing he posted on his answer, to make my query look wrong and his query the correct 1. if `a/b/c` are nulls than the output will be null as well. That's not the case presented in the question. @Boneist . In general I appreciate comments that helps me spot lacks , but not when the commenter posted an answer of his own.

Comment: @sagi Hmm, I see it as an opportunity for the answer to be improved (or at least, discussed); clearly YMMV!

Comment: Yes I agree, at least in principal. This just seemed to me as he is trying to make his answer more suitable for the OP, not that I care that much. It became a pointless argument.. :) @boniest.

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist - either here or, better, in your answer, please explain why if a term is NULL, the sum must consider it zero. That is definitely not consistent with the SQL standard (nor with logic). The result SHOULD be NULL in that case, absent a very good business reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

We Must Also handle Null Values as it will garbage out the result

```
SELECT (temp.a + temp.b + temp.c) sumTemp FROM (
  SELECT NVL(a,0) as a, NVL(b,0) as b, NVL(c,0) as c  FROM DUAL 
) temp
```

Comment: I don't understand. If one of the terms is null, why shouldn't the sum be null? It is nonsense like this that leads to very nasty bugs in most cases.

Comment: @mathguy Sir Sum == null does not make sense in arithmetic operations, so basically via NVL we are nullifying this behavior, NULL means nothing,  if a=null , b =1 , c=2 , what do u expect the sum of a+b+c? i believe there is nothing like null in Numbers of if there is kindly update my knowledge.

Comment: @mathguy may i know which bugs are you highlighting, kindly give the example and so we can bright up our knowledge with your valuable experience.

Comment: @mathguy this might help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions163.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
select aa,
       bb,
       cc,
       aa + bb + cc as total
from
(
  select 1 as aa,
         2 as bb,
         3 as cc
  from dual
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can't - not in the way you wrote it. You can't reference column aliases in building another column in the same SELECT (at the same level). Instead of `aa + bb + cc`, you will have to repeat `1, 2, 3`.

To clarify, I believe what's behind your question is something like this:

```
select   deptno, max(salary) as max_s, min(salary) as min_s, (max_s + min_s)/2 as mid_s
from     scott.emp
group by deptno
```

(trying to find the midrange salary by department, using the `EMP` table in the standard `SCOTT` schema, present in most Oracle database installations)

You can't do that - you will have to repeat `max(salary)` and `min(salary)` in the formula for the last column, or else you will need a subquery and an outer query. In almost all cases, the first choice, not the second, will be more efficient (even though it require more writing - and it may be harder to maintain).